# Add Google Analytics to iOS App through Google Tag manager

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add Google Analytics to my app using Google Tag Manager, and I can't seem to get this to work. The way I thought it worked is that I add GTM to the app, and then in my account on GTM website I add Google Analytics tags and set the tag up with my Tracking ID from my Google Analytics account (and the app I created there). I then use GTM in my app to trigger tags and track data.

And this all works fine and dandy, I send data to GTM, and I get HTTP status codes as 200 so it "works". But in Google Analytics I can't see a damn thing. Do I have to add Google Analytics to my app project as well? And do I have to use the Singletons for tracking with Google Analytics in that case? It feels like that is missing the point of what GTM is supposed to do if I have to add Google Analytics to the project as well...